# Show the terms of the hierarchical taxonomy

Tags: php, theme-development, custom-taxonomy, theme-customizer

I'm trying to display buttons with category term names.
i am using this code which works to show terms of categories which without hierarchy, but i can't figure out how to adjust it for hierarchical ones

```
$tipi_evento_names = dci_tipi_evento_array();
?>

<div class="container py-5">
    <h2 class="title-xxlarge mb-4">Esplora per categoria</h2>
    <div class="row g-4">
        <?php print_r($tipi_evento_names);
        foreach ($tipi_evento_names as $tipi_evento_name) {
            $args = array('post_type' => 'evento',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'tipi_evento',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => $tipi_evento_name,
                        'hierarchical' => 'true',
                        'hide_empty' => '0',

                    ),
                ),
            );
            $servizi = get_posts($args);
            $categoria = get_term_by('name', $tipi_evento_name, 'tipi_evento');

            $url = get_term_link( $categoria->term_id, 'tipi_evento');
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
            <div class="cmp-card-simple card-wrapper pb-0 rounded border border-light">
                <div class="card shadow-sm rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a class="text-decoration-none" href="<?php //echo $url; ?>" data-element="service-category-link">
                            <h3 class="card-title t-primary"><?php echo $categoria->name ; ?></h3>
                        </a>
                        <p class="text-secondary mb-0">
                            <?php //echo $categoria->description; ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used print_r to see what it returns
`<?php print_r($tipi_evento_names);`

and this is the array

> Array ( [Cultural event] => Array ( [Artistic event] => Array ( [0] => Festival [1] => Exhibition [2] => Theater show [3] => Dance show [4] => Musical event [5] => Guided tour [6] => Reading (public) [7] => Film screening [8] => Free visit ) [Education event] => Array ( [0] => Summer school/ winter [1] => Webinar [2] => Seminar [3] => Workshop [4] => Book presentation [5] => Course ) [Conference and Summit] => Array ( [0] => Conference [1 ] => Summit [2] => Congress ) [Information Day] => Array ( [0] => Open Day ) ) [Social Event] => Array ( [Competition and Ceremony] => Array ( [0] => Ceremony [1] => Contest/competition ) [Public debate] => Array ( [0] => Public debate/dialogue [1] => Forum ) [Meeting with experts] => Array ( [0] => Meeting of experts [1] => Hackathon / Datathon ) [Community Gathering] => Array ( [0] => Parade [1] => Festival [2] => Historical Tournament or Palio [3] => Patronal Feast or Saints [ 4] => Market [5] => Commemoration ) [Religious event] => Array ( [0] => Jubilee [1] => Jubilee audience [2] => Procession [3] => Religious celebration [4] = > Religious reading [5] => Religious gathering [6] => Sanctification ) ) [Political event] => Array ( [Public meeting] => Array ( [0] => Congress or party meeting [1] => Procession or strike [2] => Election rally ) ) [Business or commercial event] => Array ( [Fair or Show] => Array ( [0] => Fair or Show [1] => Exhibition or Global Exhibition ) [ Business meeting] => Array ( [0] => Business meeting [1] => Convention [2] => Round table ) [Seasonal commercial event] => Array ( [0] => End of season sale ) ) [Sports Event] => Array ( [Sports Event] => Array ( [0] => Match [1] => Race or Tournament or Competition [2] => Excursion [3] => Sports Gala [4] => Racing [5] => Sports rally ) ) )

These are the errors i get:

1. Warning: Attempt to read property "term_id" on bool on line 27
2. Warning: Attempt to read property "name" on bool on line 34

I'm customizing a wordpress theme and I don't have much experience, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to do it?
I took this code (and adapted it by changing the name of the taxonomy) from another file of my theme which does the same thing I have to do in this other one, the only difference I noticed is that I want to do this the terms of the taxonomy are hierarchical, while in the other they are not.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is due to the hierarchical structure of your taxonomy terms. The get_term_by() function expects a single term name as the second parameter, but in your case, the term name is an array because of the hierarchical structure.

To resolve this issue, you can modify your code to this:

```
$tipi_evento_names = dci_tipi_evento_array();

?>

<div class="container py-5">
    <h2 class="title-xxlarge mb-4">Esplora per categoria</h2>
    <div class="row g-4">
        <?php
        foreach ($tipi_evento_names as $parentName => $childArray) {
            // Get the parent term
            $parentTerm = get_term_by('name', $parentName, 'tipi_evento');
            $parentTermId = $parentTerm->term_id;
            $parentTermLink = get_term_link($parentTermId, 'tipi_evento');
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
            <div class="cmp-card-simple card-wrapper pb-0 rounded border border-light">
                <div class="card shadow-sm rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a class="text-decoration-none" href="<?php echo $parentTermLink; ?>" data-element="service-category-link">
                            <h3 class="card-title t-primary"><?php echo $parentTerm->name; ?></h3>
                        </a>
                        <p class="text-secondary mb-0">
                            <?php //echo $parentTerm->description; ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
            // Iterate over child terms
            foreach ($childArray as $childName => $grandchildArray) {
                // Get the child term
                $childTerm = get_term_by('name', $childName, 'tipi_evento');
                $childTermId = $childTerm->term_id;
                $childTermLink = get_term_link($childTermId, 'tipi_evento');
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
            <div class="cmp-card-simple card-wrapper pb-0 rounded border border-light">
                <div class="card shadow-sm rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a class="text-decoration-none" href="<?php echo $childTermLink; ?>" data-element="service-category-link">
                            <h3 class="card-title t-primary"><?php echo $childTerm->name; ?></h3>
                        </a>
                        <p class="text-secondary mb-0">
                            <?php //echo $childTerm->description; ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
                // Iterate over grandchild terms
                foreach ($grandchildArray as $grandchildName) {
                    // Get the grandchild term
                    $grandchildTerm = get_term_by('name', $grandchildName, 'tipi_evento');
                    $grandchildTermId = $grandchildTerm->term_id;
                    $grandchildTermLink = get_term_link($grandchildTermId, 'tipi_evento');
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
            <div class="cmp-card-simple card-wrapper pb-0 rounded border border-light">
                <div class="card shadow-sm rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a class="text-decoration-none" href="<?php echo $grandchildTermLink; ?>" data-element="service-category-link">
                            <h3 class="card-title t-primary"><?php echo $grandchildTerm->name; ?></h3>
                        </a>
                        <p class="text-secondary mb-0">
                            <?php //echo $grandchildTerm->description; ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
                } // End grandchild loop
            } // End child loop
        } // End parent loop
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added nested loops to iterate over the hierarchical array. The first loop retrieves the parent terms, the second loop retrieves the child terms, and the third loop retrieves the grandchild terms.

Comment: hello, thanks, now i will test it, with this code is it also possible somehow to choose not to show the category terms that have no content?